# How to update dynamic paths and re-render all pages at runtime in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

In my Next.js application, I'm leveraging dynamic routes for a specific feature. I understand that Next.js pre-renders these dynamic pages at build time using the paths returned by `getStaticPaths`.

My application's requirements necessitate adding and removing pages at runtime. These updates should ideally trigger a re-rendering of all dynamic pages, and also an update to the list of paths that Next.js knows about.

For instance, if I have a dynamic route like `[id].js` and I add a new id to my data source, I want Next.js to start rendering a page for that id without having to manually rebuild the entire application. Similarly, if an id is removed from the data source, I'd like the corresponding page to be removed as well.

From my current understanding, it seems there isn't an in-built way to re-render all dynamic paths at runtime. I'm hoping to find a solution or workaround to this constraint.

Is there a standard or recommended way to trigger re-rendering of all pages of a dynamic route at runtime in Next.js when new data is added or removed?
If not, are there alternative strategies or patterns I could adopt to achieve similar results?

I'd prefer solutions that utilize SSG for all dynamic pages, if possible. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `fallback: true` or `fallback: "blocking"` is what you are looking for.

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-static-paths#fallback-true

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-static-paths#fallback-blocking